# How did the apples fell for threads to be conceived

Tags: operating-system

I was going through the following lecture notes on OS :

http://williamstallings.com/Extras/OS-Notes/h2.html

What I could draw is that "A process is a stream of execution ,i.e.basically  a sequence of statements and so is a thread .However , the register states of one process are independent of the register states of another process but the register states of another thread can be accessed inside a thread. For every process at least one thread is allotted or dedicated ,when a process is started the OS activities for that process are taken over by the thread ( or a thread)"

What was the rationale behind conceiving the idea of threads ? When the OS is running a particular process why do we need some intermediate like a thread between them ?

"However , the register states of one process are independent of the register states of another process but the register states of another thread can be accessed inside a thread".
Can the above statement be taken as in the code for a process we cannot access the register states of a another process but in a code for a thread we can access the register states of another thread ?
(The above question did have the substitution of process and thread by their definition as codes or sequences of streams )

P.S : The title of the question is a metaphoric one .Please forgive if it misleads in any way . :P Could I take the liberty to broaden up and ask that if
the processor generates a thread for every process what does it write in the code for a thread ?(How does the code for a thread look like ? )

Answer (score 1):

Terminology - for a system with virtual memory, threads share the same virtual memory address space, while each process has it's own address space. Processes can share physical memory by having a portion of that memory shared into their virtual address spaces (but the virtual address for each process may be different even though it is the same physical memory block).

Early (1960's) instances of multi-processing were mainframes that ran multiple processes that usually did not communicate with each other. Most of this activity was for batch oriented jobs, with a stream of jobs to be run, often from a punched card reader, or in more advanced situations, from remote job entry sites, which were other computers with a few peripherals (card readers, tape drives, line printers, ... ) that communicated with the mainframe to run jobs. There were also time sharing applications, similar to servers, except in many cases, relatively dumb terminals were used to communicate with the main frame. By the 1970's, APL/SV (A Programmming Language / Share Variables) was a time sharing application / programming language that could share variables between users.

For multi-process / multi-threaded operating systems, the device drivers operate from a queue of requests (such as a file read or write). Each request to be added to a device driver queue is done similar to a context switch so there won't be conflicts between process or thread requests for I/O. Some peripherals, such as mainframe, SCSI, or ... disk drives also operated from an internal queue, and could process I/O requests out of order to reduce random access overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem that drove thread was how can an application handle multiple tasks at the same time and do it in a system-independent manner?

In classical eunuchs, a process could only do one thing at a time. If you needed to handle multiple things you kicked off multiple processes.

In the olde RSX and VMS systems (and Windoze under the covers), programmers relied on software interrupts. A process could queue I/O requests to multiple devices and receive a software interrupt when the request completed, thus allowing the application to do multiple things at once.

Another approach to the multiple things at once problem was to use event queues (Windoze, X Windows).

The ADA programming language was the first (and still really the only) mainstream programming language to support threads (tasks) as a system independent way to handle these kinds of problems. DOD compliance mandates drove the creation of threads.

Originally, threads were implemented through libraries ("use threads", "many to one model"). With the rise of multiprocessor systems, there became an increased demand to be able to have threads execute in parallel on different processors. This drove the creates of kernel threads in operating systems. (Many operating systems still do not support kernel threads).

Comment: Sorry for getting back after a long time but could you tell me what exactly do you mean by "System independent way " ?